# fwrite not fwriting when saving contents of a textarea to a file

Tags: php, textarea, fwrite

I'm making an online text editor - just a simple one for my own stuff. I'm trying to write code to save the contents of a textarea to a file - first the file is opened into the textarea (which works fine), and then I want to save the edited text. The writing isn't working. Here's the important code (my apologies for the mess, it's very early days for me and PHP):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF'];?>">
<textarea rows="30" cols="80" name="textdata"><?=$contents?></textarea>
<br />
<?php
$newcontents = $_POST["textdata"];
$openedfile = fopen($filename, "r");
fwrite($openedfile, "hello");
?>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
```

I'm sure it's something embarrassingly simple.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are opening file in `readonly` mode using `r` flag:

```
$openedfile = fopen($filename, "r");
 -------------------------------^
```

You should use `r+`, `w` or `a` (append) flag.

[See the documentation for more flags/information.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
 fopen($filename, "r");
```

is ued only for reading...

Use

```
fopen($filename, "r+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've opened the file handle in a read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

`$openedfile = fopen($filename, "r");` you are opening file for read only mode, use
`r+` instead of `r`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents), as it simplifies all the `fwrite`, `handle` and `fclose` stuff. It is generally very very easy to use this function. As taken from the documentation:

```
$file = $filename;
$text .= "Hello\n";
file_put_contents($file, $text);
```

Comment: I tried it with this code: `$newcontents = $_POST["textdata"];
file_put_contents($filename, $newcontents);`, and sadly, it still doesn't work. I know that $newcontents contains the updated version of the file, and $filename works for `file_get_contents()` earlier in the code. Could it be a permissions problem?

Comment: perhaps. check your permissions with http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php

Comment: The directory and file are both 755, which sounds about right. I've discovered that it's not that file_put_contents does nothing at all - it wipes the file clean. It must be that whatever is in $newcontents gets lost between the textarea and the function.

Comment: you can add a third argument which appends the string to the file.

Comment: Appending isn't important - the textarea shows the whole file, I edit it, and then the whole file can be written back over onto the sever. It's just that that isn't working. I'll keep poking it.